# Set and call Fragment Tag correct

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can't get rid of this problem. I saw a couple other questions with a similar problem, but nothing fixed it.

Short story: I replace my placeholders with fragments in my MainActivty and would like to call a public method from that new fragment. But calling the fragment from his Tag, leads to a "Null object reference" error.
I tried multiple ways to set and call the Tag but without success

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:menu="@menu/quick_settings"
tools:context="....">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
        ...
```

Main.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_annual_service);
    createList();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private void createList() {

    Resources r = getResources();
    String packageName = getPackageName();

    //Array with all Fragments
    fragmentList = new Fragment[]{
                new FragmentA,
                new FragmentB,
                new FragmentC,
               ...
        };
    numberOfFragments = fragmentList.length;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    for (int arrayIndex=0, fragmentNumber=1; fragmentNumber <= numberOfFragments; arrayIndex++, fragmentNumber++){

        fragmentTransaction.replace(r.getIdentifier("fragment" + fragmentNumber, "id", packageName), fragmentList[arrayIndex], "fragment0"+fragmentNumber); // also try to set the TagName

    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    ((Unfold)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment01")).unfold(); // Method is implemented by a interface
```

FragmentA.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FragmentA"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="45dp"
        android:visibility="gone">
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentA.java

```
Button backBtn;
TextView header;
LinearLayout llayout;
Drawable defaulBG;
View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return setListener(inflater, container);
}

private View setListener(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general_information, container, false);
    header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.generalInformationHeaderText);
    header.setOnClickListener(this);
    llayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    defaulBG = inForkliftBtn.getBackground();
    backBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    return view;
}

public void unfold(){
    if(llayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        llayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        llayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: try with `fragmentManager.findFragmentById(<the container id>)`

Comment: already tried it but the same null reference error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `executePendingTransactions()` on fragment manager after committing transaction

```
...
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
((Unfold)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment01")).unfold();
```

**EDIT 1**

You can try another option:

1. **Do not** add the executePendingTransactions()
2. In fragment's onViewCreated, if `getTag()` mathes "fragment01" call `unfold` method

Comment: this seems to work. But now there is another error. In the method unfold() I try to check the visibility of a LinearLayout. 
`llayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE`
But now I get a "Null object reference" error. Before the problem from above it worked.
Is the OnCreateView() Method not executed before calling the unfold() method?

Comment: @WeSt 
onCreateView calls when you attach fragment to activity. In your case you just get object. But
may  fragment state is not be saved and instance variables are null. Try call setRetainInstance(true) in fragment&amp;amp;#39;s onCreate(or onCreateView) it may fix error

Comment: `setRetainInstance(true);` in onCreateView() of the Fragment don't fix the problem. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @WeSt can you post full Mainacitivity and Fragment code?

Comment: I added the important parts to my post

Comment: @WeSt try use add instead of replace in transaction

Comment: still the same null object reference error on the getVisibility()